# Adding a background image to a plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Say I am plotting a set of points with an image as a background. I've used the [Lena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N32KD.jpg) image in the example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,15)
y = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,15)
img = imread("lena.jpg")
plt.scatter(x,y,zorder=1)
plt.imshow(img,zorder=0)
plt.show()
```

This gives me[image] .

My question is: How can I specify the corner coordinates of the image in the plot? Let's say I'd like the bottom-left corner to be at `x, y = 0.5, 1.0` and the top-right corner to be at `x, y = 8.0, 7.0`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the `extent` keyword of `imshow`. The order of the argument is `[left, right, bottom, top]`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,15)
y = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,15)

datafile = 'lena.jpg'
img = plt.imread(datafile)
plt.scatter(x,y,zorder=1)
plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[0.5, 8.0, 1.0, 7.0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

- For cases where it's desired to have an image in a small area of the scatter plot, change the order of the plots (`.imshow` then `.scatter`) and change the `extent` values.

```py
plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.50])
plt.scatter(x, y, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. The only thing I had to add is to set `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` otherwise the viewport/axes are fitted tightly to the background image.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you YXD! Just wanted to add in case someone encountered the same: if you do plt.scatter(), then plt.imshow(), the figure may be covered by the image, with sized defined in "extent" kwarg. If this is the case you had, try: do plt.imshow() first, then plt.scatter(). Then you will have a figure, with size determined by your data (x,y), and images displayed on the graph.

Answer (score 12):

You must use the `extent` keyword parameter:

```
imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[left, right, bottom, top])
```

The elements of extent should be specified in data units so that the image can match the data. This can be used, for example, to overlay a geographical path (coordinate array) over a geo-referenced map image.