# How to avoid change of aspect when adding a background image with matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, imshow

I want to some data with a background image using matplotlib.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160123/adding-a-background-image-to-a-plot-with-known-corner-coordinates) that I need to use `extent`.

However, if the range of my data is not the same the plot scales as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,10),ylim=(0,1))
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,15)
y = np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,15)
img = imread('lena.jpg')
ax.scatter(x,y,zorder=1)
ax.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[0.5, 8.0, 0.0, 1.0])
```

How can I keep the limits of my axes and avoid the scaling?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlibs `imshow` sets the aspect ratio of the axes automatically. You can change this behaviour by setting the `aspect` argument.

```
ax.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[0.5, 8.0, 0.0, 1.0], aspect='auto')
```

You'll find more detailed information in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow).