# pyplot: dotted background and dotted rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to get a dotted background like the following picture?

[image]

The only method I know is to upload a picture of dots and fill in the plot with that picture according to this post:[Adding a background image to a plot with known corner coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160123/adding-a-background-image-to-a-plot-with-known-corner-coordinates)

Comment: Do you only want to have a dotted background or you want to do something else? You could use `grid`, you could use `scatter`, you could use `plot`... Please, try to explain better what you want to do.

Comment: I want a dotted "background".(It's not a dot/scatter plot. There is no data. It is a background.)

Comment: Well, define background :-) Do you want to plot something 'over' the 'background'?

Comment: Yes. After I have the background, I want to have some basic plotting over that background.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, with this ugly hack you can have dots wherever you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


y = np.random.randn(100) * 100
x = np.arange(len(y))

for xi in x:
    ybg = np.arange(np.int(y.min())-1, np.int(y.max()+1))
    xbg = np.repeat(xi, len(ybg))
    plt.plot(xbg, ybg, '.k', alpha = 0.25)

plt.plot(x, y, 'b', lw = 3)
```

Controlling `xbg` and `ybg` you can control where your dots will be plotted so you don't have to mind about an image background.