# Plotting a graph with a picture as a background and another picture as the plot points

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is what I tried to do. It displayed the image as the background but it did not display the x,y plot. I also want to use another picture for my plot points.

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]       
y=[0,1,2,3,4,5]    

im = plt.imread('testimage.png')

implot = plt.imshow(im)

plt.plot(x,y,'o',color='black')

plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see that it works, but when you draw the image each unit in the plot equals one pixel, so if your image is 512x512 and you plot the points x and y these will be located in the upper left.

Comment: yes, that is endeed what happens. any idea how to not have the x and y at the upper left corner? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a background image to a plot with known corner coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160123/adding-a-background-image-to-a-plot-with-known-corner-coordinates)

Comment: You code needs the import to tell what `plt` is.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  If the missing import is for matplotlib, add the tag so matplotlib experts are more likely to look at this.